# Find the locus of $|\frac{z}{z-4}|=5$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles, absolute-value, locus

I have been asked to find the locus and the Cartesian equation of $\left|\frac{z}{z-4}\right|=5$.

I have tried several different ways and have got no easily sketchable graph. $|z|=5|z-4|$

I have tried expanding this and gotten nowhere, help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is $z$ assumed to be a complex number?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Square both sides of the equation that you have written down and expand from there.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+yi,$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Thus, by your work we obtain:
$$x^2+y^2=25((x-4)^2+y^2).$$
Can you end it now?

I got a circle $$\left(x-\frac{25}{6}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$$ without two points for $x=4$.

Comment: Why without two points? It should be a full circle (mapped to $|z| = 5$ by a Mobius transformation).

Comment: @Maxim See please an original question and attempt of the topic starter. It's $|\frac{z}{z-4}|=5.$ I'll fix it.

Comment: The points $z = 4 \pm i \sqrt {\smash [b] {2/3}}$ satisfy the equation, there's nothing special about them.